# Angular: why does view get re-rendered even when change detection detects no change?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  //name = 'Angular';

  onClick(){
    //this.name = 'hey';
  }

  check(){
    console.log('wow');
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Click</button>
{{check()}}
```

When I run this, '`wow`' gets printed on the console initially 4 times (not sure why 4 times, but let's leave that). The main thing is that when I click on the button, '`wow`' gets printed (twice) even though I have changed nothing in the template expressions.

As I understand it, when an event, etc occurs, change detection takes place which compares fields used in expressions and property binding in template. If a change is detected, the view is re-rendered. But in this case, the view is being re-rendered (as shown by the calling of `check` method) even when no change should have been detected

Stacklitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbytxe)

Comment: Changes are being detected on several lifehooks in Angular.

Comment: Any async operations and eventhadlers will trigger change detection and view rendering. in short they overwrite the native ones and some from libs like rxjs to get this effect working. See it like that you evaluate the return of a function in the html. How should angular know that nothing changed without evaluating the funtion and the included console log. Just replace the console log with `return Date.now().toString()` and you will see how it works

Comment: Also since you (probably) are in dev mode, every check is run twice to tell the dev, if the view changed after it should not have changed... The two detection you are seeing are, `ngOnInit` and `ngOnChange`. Init is normal, and change run after init once too, don't remember why tho...

Answer (score 0):

In the angular documentation for the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) it mentions

> Components are normally marked as dirty (in need of rerendering) when
> inputs have changed or events have fired in the view.

So in this case, since you have triggered the `click` event, the view is marked as dirty and will re-render.

If you are looking for a fix then you can use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or you can dive a little deeper into the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and turn off change detection on certain components.

If you are looking for more of an overview of change detection I would recommend [this article](https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7).

If you want to know the lifecycles that are causing this to happen they are `AfterViewChecked` and `AfterContentChecked`

Comment: Since the "check" method can only be called when view is re-rendered, and the view can only be re-rendered once change detection detects a change, and change detection couldn't possibly have detected any change in this component, then why is the "check" method being called?

Comment: I think I found the answer you are looking for. I updated my answer above.

Comment: So I guess the view is re-rendered whenever an event fires, even when there's no actual change detected in the change detection process? That would be very inefficient, no? I think in my example, re-rendering of the whole component is not taking place.. its just that the expression in the template has to be evaluated as part of change detection (as explained by Muchsh in the comment under the question)

Comment: Yes it is rather inefficient but the view rendering usually doesn't take that long, so isn't that bad. Just note this and make sure that you don't use to expensive calls and to many components that have to be rendered all the time. Also some libs that use many async calls and event handlers can be a problem. In this case you can use `NgZone.runOutsideAngular(()=>...)` to wrap the calls there they are created, that prevents this behavior `NgZone.run(()=>...)` reenables it. In this case you can use a `console.log` on `NgZone.onUnstable` to debug when the change detection was triggert